# Can I make a repeat action into a function keystroke

Tags: mac

I use Safari to gather information in my family history research, and when I get new names to add to my ‘Tree” I like to capitalise the surnames. Can I do this with keystrokes instead of going to edit/transformations/capitalise every time?

Answer (score 1):

You can add key commands for any menu item in any app, or even globally.

For one like this, globally might be the best approach - I actually use it in Safari as well as TextEdit.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Click the + button, select All Applications then type your menu name
You don't need to specify any hierarchy, it'll just find it no matter how many sub-menus deep it is.

Add your key command - make it something you're not going to be using elsewhere

Done.

[image]

Note for future ref. If you need to access a menu item with ellipsis [3 dots] that it is not the same as 3 full stops [periods] ...  it's a true ellipsis … [hard to tell the difference in here, but they are different characters.]

Comment: Thank you so much for this (very easy) solution - now I know the means I can make multiple instant access changes (just as it seems you have done)

Comment: Welcome :) As you possibly noticed, you can also use this to remove 'annoying' shortcuts, such as my 5-key-combo for Hide Finder, by changing it to something you'll never hit by accident.